# Why does this comprehension return a generator?

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension

This is a follow up question I read just now : [DataFrame, apply, lambda, list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180102/dataframe-apply-lambda-list-comprehension#51180102).

So I tried the following code

```
import pandas as pd

# This is a dataframe containing the correct values
correct = pd.DataFrame([{"letters":"abc","data":1},{"letters":"ast","data":2},{"letters":"bkgf","data":3}])

# This is the dataframe containing source data
source = pd.DataFrame([{"c":"ab"},{"c":"kh"},{"c":"bkg"}])

temp_result = source["c"].apply(lambda x: i for (i,row) in correct.values)
```

So i tried different variations like this

```
temp_result = source["c"].apply(lambda x: i for (i,row) in correct.iteritems())
```

Yet all return the error :`Genrator object is not callable`
So my question is why is it returning a generator instead of treating it as a list of items ? I know what generator expressions are, but I am not able to understand why this expression is being treated as a generator instead of a list comprehension (or a lambda expression )?

Comment: Currently you're passing a generator to apply. If you meant that to be a lambda *returning* a generator, you need to add parentheses.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I am not exactly sure where to add the paranthesis since I think the lambda syntax will become incorrect ? Can you please give an example or show the correct expression :)

Comment: `lambda x: (...)`. But it's not clear to me what output you were expecting.

Comment: try `lambda x: [i for (i,row) in correct.iteritems()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list comprehensions have the `[]` square brackets.
if you don't have the `[]` square brackets, you have a generator expression

```
.apply(lambda x: (i for (i,row) in correct.iteritems()))
```

The code above would make a function that returns a generator expression, and pass  it to the `.apply`

```
.apply([lambda x: i for (i,row) in correct.iteritems()])
```

The code above would create a list of functions, and pass that list to  `.apply`

```
.apply(lambda x: [i for (i,row) in correct.iteritems()])
```

The code above would make a function that returns a list, and pass  it to the `.apply`.

Comment: So there is no way to modify this expression so that it contains `lambda` and also a list comprehension ?

Comment: if you really want list comprehension, you have to add square brackets. Otherwise you can't make a list comprehension. @MohammedKashif

Comment: Thanks! it worked :) I actually didn't knew about this case of `apply` and `generators`. Learned something new today :)

Comment: The list comprehension of lambdas probably won't behave as expected, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021333/3001761